# spring BOOT ignores CORS configuration after update to SecurityFilterChain

Tags: spring, cors

i am trying to update this SecurityFilterChain in order to avoid deprecated methods

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationConfiguration.class)), this.userRepository), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).authorizeRequests()
        .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/public/**")).permitAll()
        .expressionHandler(null)
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
     return http.build();
}
```

it works but is deprecated, so i came up with this:

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.cors((cors)->cors.disable());
     http.csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable());
     http.sessionManagement((sessionManagement) -> sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
     http.addFilterBefore(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationConfiguration.class)), this.userRepository), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
     http.authorizeHttpRequests((request) -> request.requestMatchers("/public/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated());

    return http.build();
}
```

and it works partially. I have 2 paths, /public and /private. Requests for /public works as expected with CORS, but when i invoke a /protected api i have a CORS error. It is very strange, both controllers are annotated with `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")`.
Any suggestion?

Comment: If you want to avoid those CORS errors, you'll need to _enable_ (not disable) CORS. Take the time to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: i have tryed substituting `http.cors((cors)->cors.disable());` with `http.cors()` (also if deprecated) and nothing changes. also tryed defining a CorsConfigurationSource to enable cors globally but nothing changes

Comment: ok, defining a CorsConfigurationSource and explicitly configure it with `http.cors((cors)->cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()));` works

Answer (score 1):

i had to configure CORS globally, defining a CorsConfigurationSource as follows:

```
     @Bean
     CorsConfigurationSource  corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.applyPermitDefaultValues();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "DELETE"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
     }
```

and than set it to CORS with `http.cors((cors)->cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()));` instead of `http.cors((cors)->cors.disable());`